# Derived class implementing multiple interfaces with a common function signature

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm getting a compile error when I try to compile my code.
The error is this:

```
multi.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
multi.cc:35: error: cannot declare variable ‘mdc’ to be of abstract type ‘MostDerivedClass’
multi.cc:27: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘MostDerivedClass’:
multi.cc:13: note:  virtual int Interface2::common_func()
multi.cc:36: error: request for member ‘common_func’ is ambiguous
multi.cc:13: error: candidates are: virtual int Interface2::common_func()
multi.cc:21: error:                 virtual int InterimClass::common_func()
```

And here is my code:

```
class Interface1 {
public:
    virtual int common_func() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface1() {};
};

class Interface2 {
public:
    virtual int common_func() = 0;
    virtual int new_func() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface2() {};
};


class InterimClass : public Interface1 {
public:
    virtual int common_func() {
        return 10;
    }
};


class MostDerivedClass : public InterimClass, public Interface2 {
public:
    virtual int new_func() {
        return 20;
    }   
};

int main() {
    MostDerivedClass mdc;
    int x = mdc.common_func();
    cout << "The value = " << x << endl;    

    Interface2 &subset_of_funcs = dynamic_cast<Interface2 &>(mdc);
    x = subset_of_funcs.common_func();
}
```

My questions:

- How do I tell the compiler that common_func() is already implemented by the InterimClass which is a base class of MostDerivedClass?
- Is there another way to fix my problem?  What I would really like to do is to be able to also call common_func from Interface2.  I'm working with some legacy code with a huge amount of methods in Interface1.  In my new code, I only want to call a small set of these Interface1 functions, plus a few that I need to add.

Comment: Your common function is not actually 'common'. `Interface1::common_func()` has nothing common with `Interface2::common_func()`. If you want actually common function, you should derive `Interface2` from `Interface1`. And then apply @juanchopanza answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a `common_func()` anyway in `MostDerivedClass` to satisfy your inheritance from `Interface2`

you can try something like

```
virtual int common_func() {
    return InterimClass::common_func();
}
```

This is most useful if you cannot change the first `Interface1`

If you want a real inheritance relationship between your classes you need to follow Lol4t0 advice. Extract a superclass from `Interface1`, and make `Interface2` subclass of this newly created class. Example :

```
class RootInterface{
public :
    virtual int common_func() = 0;
    virtual ~RootInterface(){}
};

class Interface1 : public virtual RootInterface{
public:
    virtual ~Interface1() {};
};

class Interface2 : public virtual RootInterface{
    public:
    virtual int new_func() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface2() {};
};

class InterimClass : public Interface1 {
    public:
    virtual int common_func() {
        return 10;
    }
};

class MostDerivedClass : public InterimClass, public Interface2 {
public:
    virtual int new_func() {
        return 20;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an override in MostDerivedClass, and from it call InterimClass::common_func().

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't really understand the sense of your code.

You need to know that only Interface1::common_func is implemented.

Why don't you make Interface2 inherit from Interface1? I guess you want for both common_func methods to be equal.

Example code (uses polymorphism):

```
class Interface1 
{
public:
    virtual int common_func() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface1() {};
};

class Interface2 : public Interface1 {
public:
    virtual int common_func() = 0;
    virtual int new_func() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface2() {};
};

class InterimClass : public Interface2 {
    public:
        virtual int common_func() {
            return 10;
        }
};

class MostDerivedClass : public InterimClass {
public:
    virtual int new_func() {
        return 20;
    }
};

int test_func()
{
    Interface1 * i1 = new MostDerivedClass;
    int x = i1->common_func();
    cout << "The value = " << x << endl;

    Interface2 * i2 = new MostDerivedClass;
    x = i2->common_func();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just hesitate to make changes to existing code.  Hopefully, at some time later, I can refactor the code to reflect a new inheritance structure.

Answer (score 0):

Let the second interface be derived from the first interface, remove the declaration of `virtual int common_func() = 0;` from the second interface, & use the keyword virtual to guide the compiler to the implementation.

```
class Interface1 {
public:
    virtual int common_func() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface1() {};
};

class BaseClass : public virtual Interface1 {
public:
    virtual int common_func() {
        return 10;
    }
};

class Interface2 : public virtual Interface1{
public:
    virtual int new_func() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface2() {};
};

class DerivedClass : public virtual BaseClass, public virtual Interface2 {
public:
    virtual int new_func() {
        return 20;
    }   
};
```